# Getting gocr to use the database

Tags: ocr

I'm trying to get gocr to do recognize text in a png. I run gocr using the following:

```
gocr -p ../db/ -m 386 output-4.png
```

the -m 386 option switches off the recognition engine, and extends the database (prompts user for unidentified characters and extends the database with users answer) according to the man pages.

gocr prompts me for characters it doesn't recognize, and I tell it what the characters are - it then produces a perfect (near enough) document from the png.

So I rerun gocr using:

```
gocr -p ../db/ -m 258 output-4.png
```

Here the -m 258 option switches off character recognition algorithms and tells gocr to match characters from the database. But now it outputs lots of unrecognized characters. Shouldn't it be producing the same output that I obtained after training the database?

I can turn on matching using algorithms (and then getting gocr to match characters from the database when it cannot find a match) but then it introduces lots of errors, eg identifying a "9" as a "g", or a "0" as an "o" and so on.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You may train gocr with -a 100 flag, which should ask you about more characters. That worked for me. So:

```
gocr -p ../db/ -m 386 -a 100 output-4.png
```